# WAFDetect Extension of Burpsuite

Tags: burp-suite, fingerprinting, waf

I am creating a list of tools for waf fingerprinting.
I have installed [waf-detect](https://portswigger.net/bappstore/bapps/details/12bef6b7607e46cf965c16f76e905a4c) plugin from bapp store in burpsuite. 
This plugin runs in the background and create passive scanner issues when WAF traces are detected. How I can see the result of this plugin? I didn't find any new tab in burpsuite to check the output of this plugin.
Can you suggest me some tools for waf fingerprinting.
Currently best tool I found is https://github.com/EnableSecurity/wafw00f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the issues in Target > Site map. Select a node in the left-hand tree and the related issues appear on the right.

Suggesting tools is a separate question. This site tends to close questions that ask for tools recommendations. To maximize your chances, phrase your question as "How do I...?"